# How to add class after uploading an image?

Tags: javascript, image-upload

Why this code is not working?

```
 function previewFile() {
    var preview = document.querySelector('img');
    var file    = document.querySelector('input[type=file]'='class="rounded-circle"').files[0];
    var reader  = new FileReader();

    reader.addEventListener("load", function () {
        preview.src = reader.result;
    }, false);

    if (file) {
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }
}
```

I want to add class of `rounded-circle` after uploading an image.

Comment: Reminder that "not working" is not a sufficient description of any problem.  When asking a question, describe _expected results_ vs _actual results_ and provide any error messages.

Comment: i think the value of file selector is  not valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
reader.addEventListener("load", function () {
    preview.src = reader.result;
    preview.classList.add("rounded-circle");
}, false);
```